# CSS Vertically and horizontally align div without knowing width and height

Tags: css

How do I vertically and horizontally align a div without knowing its width and height?

example:

```
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"> 
    <div id="FancyOverlay" style="  position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:green;">
        <div id="Grandparents" style="position:absolute; left:50%; z-index:1;">
            <div id="Parent" style="position: relative; left:-50%; padding:10px; border:1px solid black;">
                <img id="fancyImage" src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Test this code so you can see what I'm trying to do. #Parent needs to be in the center of the screen. I've already aligned it horizontally but I can't get it vertically to work.

btw:
I dont know the width and the height of the image, this was just an example.

Comment: your question is not clear. can your tell me, exactly what you want do?

Comment: so basically #Parent needs to be aligned in the center of the screen

Comment: you understand the question now?

Comment: did u got what you want?